# click multiple buttons with same class names in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image]

This a column in a table this column contains buttons, on pressing each buttons a pdf is downloaded

The buttons have the same class names and I want to click on all the buttons.

This is what I did, but it doesnt work:

```
addinfo = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btnAddInfo')
for x in addinfo:
    if addinfo[x].is_displayed():
        addinfo[x].click()
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a little bit vague. What is the expected effect and what is the obtained effect? The first thing I'd think is that `find_element_by_class_name` does what it says it does: it will find the element with that class name. If you want to find them *all* and put them in a list you have to use `find_elements_by_class_name` (note the plural).

Comment: `for` doesn't give you number/index of element but directly this element - so you need `x.is_displayed()` and `x.click()`

Comment: BTW: always put in question FULL error message (Traceback). Text `"Doesn't work"` is useless without error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hi First get the reference of the parent container in which all these buttons reside and then you will have to get the button reference which you would like to click by passing unique parameters to the method which identities the button which you want to click

```
public IWebElement GetButtontoClick(IWebElement prObj, string propName, string propVlu)
    {
        IWebElement btnToClick = null;
        try
        {
            //get the list of all buttons in the prObj
            IList<IWebElement> btnlList = prObj.FindElements(By.ClassName("xyz"));

            //iterate through each button element and find the button you want to click
            for (int i = 0; i < btnlList.Count; i++)
            {
                IWebElement btn = btnlList[i];

                var btnPropValue = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)DriverContext.Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0]."+ propName+"; ", btn);
                if (propVlu == btnPropValue.ToString())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have found the button you want to click");
                    btnToClick = btn;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return btnToClick;
    }
```

How to call this method

```
//i know outerHTML is too big just for example sake i have give  that you can provide any unique property name and unique property value which differentiates one button from other,outerHTML is one such property
IWebElement myButton = GetButtontoClick(prObj, "outerHtml", "outerHTMLValue")
```

Hope this works.