# Click same id buttom selenium PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
    from selenium import webdriver
import time

username = ""
password = ""

getdriver = ("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(getdriver)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log in')]").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/python.coders/followers/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a').click()
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_name('Follow').click()
```

I want to click all Follow display buttom on instagram,i can not do it with tag_name or name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use findElements.
- It returns a list of WebElements with same locator.
- Now loop around the size of this list and keep on clicking the WebElements.

Comment: in that case can you please share some html of the page. May be then we can help you around some different locator.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/python.coders/followers/ go here, i want to click all follow blue buttoms

Comment: well what I see is a <ul> tag and inside it a list of <li> tags. Use by css locator and as a locator use "ul li:nth-of-type(i) button" where i is the index you want to access. ex : "ul li:nth-of-type(3) button" will click on 3rd follow button.

Comment: yeas its working but its click one button many tames not click anothers.

Comment: and i want to click all follow buttoms not one

Comment: Like This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715980/click-multiple-buttons-with-same-class-names-in-python

Comment: for i in range(1,3):
    like = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul li:nth-of-type{} button'.format(i)).click()

Comment: how you getul li:nth-of-type(i) button??

Comment: "ul li:nth-of-type(i) button" its css locator for a button you want to click. regarding clicking all buttons. you need to run it in loop where i is loop iteration number.